# Need help resetting PSQL Settings

Tags: postgresql

I am new to database management and I am doing a university project. When I was done with the creation of the database and the needed queries, I no longer wanted to permanently copy/paste dozens of lines I had written one by one to delete my table entries or to reprint them all. Basically, I went ahead and made two SQL files I could run from my PSQL session to delete everything or to print all tables and their values.

I managed to do the first file correctly and without problems. However, when I was doing the second "Script", which basically was supposed to mimic this:

```
select * from table1;
select * from table2;
.
.
.
select * from tableN;
```

And since my knowledge is very limited on SQL and this wasn't asked at all as part of the project I went ahead and tryed some "source codes" I found around, I know very unprofessional. Point is... None of them worked, so I went ahead and just made a ABC.sql file in which all the selects I mentioned above were written. At least like that, I could print them all out writting one simple line instead of copy/pasting all the lines I had written.

The problem is, after running those codes I found lying around on Stackoverflow, whenever I do a select * from tableX, instead of getting a pretty printed table I get something like this:

```
-[ RECORD 36 ]+--------------------------
ean         | 2259191076425
designation | Iogurte Morango
category    | Iogurte
supplier    | 111716311
data        | 2017-04-11
```

For every row of each table and I can't figure out how to reset it back to normal. :(

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have turned on [expanded mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html). To reset just type `\x` on psql.